# Check a host file for modification and if missing add it

Tags: scripts, sed, awk, hosts

I'm using docker in which the container has its own /etc/hosts file.  It gets cleared out when rebooting.  I'd like to create a script to check for an entry and if missing add it.

So if /etc/hosts has an entry that says:

```
10.1.1.1 important-server
```

Then do nothing.  If not do:

```
echo "10.1.1.1 important-server" >> /etc/hosts
```

I'm assuming I can use `sed` or `awk` or something like that for the pattern matching.

Comment: You should add `--add-host="import-server:10.1.1.1"` to the docker run command OR docker-compose.yml file if you use docker-compose.

Comment: `grep` with the option `-q` will `exit 0`(*success*) at first match and will `exit > 0` otherwise ... So, ... `/bin/grep -Fq '10.1.1.1 important-server' /etc/hosts || echo "10.1.1.1 important-server" >> /etc/hosts`

Comment: Already gave a response of this earlier ;) And the spaces are not fixed like this in **RealLife©®™**

Comment: --add-host "import-server:10.1.1.1" works.  It should not have the =

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by **Rinzwind** in comments:

> You should add `--add-host="import-server:10.1.1.1"` to the docker run command OR docker-compose.yml file if you use docker-compose.

Or in shell:

```
sudo -s
grep -Pq '^10\.1\.1\.1\s+important-server' /etc/hosts ||
    echo '10.1.1.1 important-server' >> /etc/hosts
exit
```

Comment: Correct except change = to :